# Upgrade via Composer shows errors

Tags: composer, 10, upgrading

I'm trying to upgrade Drupal 9.5.11 to Drupal 10 via composer.

The upgrade status module shows everything is ok. I've disabled every module except the toolbar and configuration manager. I've done this

```
composer remove drupal/console --no-update
chmod 777 web/sites/default
chmod 666 web/sites/default/*settings.php
chmod 666 web/sites/default/*services.yml
composer require 'drupal/core-recommended:^10' 'drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^10' 'drupal/core-project-message:^10' --no-update
composer update
composer install
drush updatedb
chmod 755 web/sites/default
chmod 644 web/sites/default/*settings.php
chmod 644 web/sites/default/*services.yml
```

It all seems to go ok but whn I go to my site I get these sorts of errors;

On the main site front page;

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later.

`Drupal\Core\Asset\Exception\InvalidLibrariesExtendSpecificationException: The specified library "olivero/dialog.off_canvas" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryCollector->applyLibrariesExtend() (line 155 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/LibraryDiscoveryCollector.php)`.
```

On the admin page;

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later.

InvalidArgumentException: The callable definition provided "`[Drupal\Core\Render\Element\HtmlTag,preRenderConditionalComments]" is not a valid callable. in Drupal\Core\Utility\CallableResolver->getCallableFromDefinition() (line 69 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Utility/CallableResolver.php).`
```

The original nodes come from Drupal 7.97 and I successfully migrated to 9.5.11 where I disabled and removed all contributed modules.

All I want to move are my nodes from the 9.5.11 installation to Drupal 10. Been at it for days and days. Tried everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was a drush problem where my drush command was using drush from a different drupal installation. Once I fixed this the dependencies updated correctly and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

The error is apt: `olivero/dialog.off_canvas` has been removed in Drupal 10. I encourage you to search the site's codebase for `olivero/dialog.off_canvas`. There is probably custom or contributed code that tried to load the now-removed library. By providing more information about that, we could make this answer more detailed.